# How to avoid cumulative rounding errors when calculating a result to a specific number of significant figures?

Tags: rounding-error, significant-figures

I have two operands and I want to calculate the result of an arithmetic operation (add, sub, mul, div, pow, sqrt, ln...) to `S` significant figures. How many significant figures do I need in the operands to achieve this result without rounding of the least significant digit?

For example, let's consider a context of "always accurate to 2 significant figures".

0.123 * 0.456 = 0.056088, rounded to 0.056 (2 s.f).

If we keep using that result for future calculations within this context, we'll get rounding errors because we've lost data along the way. My question is: **could I avoid rounding errors in the current context by calculating the result to precision + x**?

For example, with the same context (always accurate to 2 s.f), we can calculate to 4 s.f:

0.123 * 0.456 = 0.056088, rounded to 0.05609. Could I now use this result without losing accuracy along the way? Or would the rounding inevitable cause inaccuracy?

Comment: You might be interested in [propagation of uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no answer.  Subtraction makes it easy to see.  If you want to subtract $1.0000000-0.9999999$ to two significant figures you need to carry a lot of figures.  For multiplication and division the problem comes from the fact that a chance of $1$ in the third place is a chance of $1\%$ in $1.00$ but $0.1\%$ in $9.99$.  The fractional error is maintained with multiplication and division.  Functions like pow and log are also problematic.

Added: even worse, $\frac 1x-\frac 2{x+1}+\frac 1{x+2}$ is about $\frac 2{x^3}$ for large $x$.  If $x \approx 1000$ you need to keep $11$ places to get $2$ places out at the end.  We can keep going like this.

Comment: Wikipedia states to "keep as many digits as is practical (at least 1 more than implied by the precision of the final result) until the end of calculation to avoid cumulative rounding errors." https://graylab.jhu.edu/courses/540.202/docs/Significant_Figures.pdf

Is that wrong?

Comment: What if you use something like MAX(op1.precision, op2.precision) + 1? In the case you mentioned, that would be MAX(8, 7) + 1, ie. calculated to 9 significant figures to avoid cumulative rounding errors.

Comment: I can design even more pathological cases that break that.  $\ln x$ for $x$ near zero will be hard. More extra places is better because errors become rarer, but you can’t eliminate them

Comment: If that rule works for +,-,\*,/,%, and a different rule is required for ln, that would be acceptable. If such a rule is *possible*, I would like to find out what it is.

Comment: See my added example, that just uses arithmetic and points the way to make it as bad as you want.

Comment: Knowing $a$ and $b$ up to an error of at most $\varepsilon$, the difference $a-b$ is known up to an error of at most $2\varepsilon$. So if you round $a,b$ to $3$ significant figures ($\varepsilon=10^{-3}/2$) then rounding the correct $a-b$ to $2$ decimals and rounding the difference of the rounded values to $2$ decimals *will* give the same result, right?

Comment: @Christoph: no, look at my first example.  The problem is that $a-b$ can be much smaller in magnitude than either $a$ or $b$, so $\frac \varepsilon{a-b}$ can be very large.  If you round $a$ and $b$ to three or four decimals the difference comes out $0$, which is a huge fractional error.

Comment: I misunderstood "significant figures" as "decimal places in an expression without a factor $10^k$", sorry.

Comment: @Christoph:  you are correct for absolute error, but OP asked about maintaining significant figures.

Comment: @RossMillikan we're not "rounding to decimal places", we're rounding to significant figures. Magnitude doesn't matter.

Comment: @rtheunissen:  yes, I believe my examples have followed that.  One problem is that addition and subtraction maintain absolute error while multiplication and division maintain relative error.  Keeping one extra place for multiplication and division works very well but in addition and subtraction you can get the cancellation I am showing.

Comment: The answer to the example when x is 1000 is 2.0e-9, which you can achieve by using 7 significant figures (I think). Knowing that 1001 has 4 significant figures, what about using twice the precision for addition and subtraction? Seems a bit arbitrary though.

Comment: No, that won't work.  The fact that it is cubic in $x$ means you would need three times the number of digits in this computation.  $10^n+1 $ has $n+1$ significant digits and we need $3n+$ a few to get a sensible answer out.  If we make a version that goes as $x^{-4}$ you would need four times as many and so on.